# How to show a reference of the shared assembly in the .net add reference dialog window?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, dll, shared-libraries

Q:

I make a dll and put it in the global assembly cache `(GAC)`,now i wanna to use this dll in my application , but i can't see any reference to it.
When
`Add reference ----> dialog window --->no reference` to my shared assembly .i don't see any reference .

how to fix this problem.

to make my shared assembly , i do the following:

1-Right click on my project file ---> properties --->Signing tab ---> choose a strong name.

2- In the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file add this line

`[assembly: AssemblyKeyFile("C:\\Users\\just_name\\Downloads\\New folder\\testingGAC\\testingGAC\\key.snk")]` then build the solution.

3- Drag the `testingGAC.dll` file into the assembly folder in my c:\

Is there any problems with these steps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of referenes doesn't actually work off the GAC - there's a registry key at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders that controls which folders get looked at when creating this list.

This [link](http://www.csharp411.com/adding-assemblies-to-the-visual-studio-add-reference-dialog/) has the full low-down on the process

Comment: thanks alot .
`C:\Users\just_name\Downloads\New folder\testingGAC\testingGAC\bin\Debug`
i forget to write this part `\bin\Debug`.

Comment: No worries - took ages to figure this out first time I came across it!

Comment: please, if i wanna to modify the shared assembly code, and then build , and remove and add refernece to my application . no change ,how to reflect the change in the dll to the application which use this dll.

Comment: Do you just need to update the reference? If you're still developing then you may want to (temporarily) include the shared assembly in your solution and reference it as a project - shared locations are best for build and tested assemblies.

Comment: `Could not load type 'testingGAC.testClass' from assembly 'testingGAC, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5f8c2d6dfc9f4371'.`

Comment: Sounds like this is turning into a new question.

Comment: hhh, sorry it works when i close `the ASP.net developemnet` sever ..thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the assembly in the GAC folder using the [Global Assembly Cache Tool (Gacutil.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Next install/register the assembly, then follow these steps to add reference:

> Expand the project and then right-click on the References item. Select "Add Reference" from the popup menu, and the Add Reference dialog box is displayed.
>
> To refer an assembly in the GAC, just
>   click on the Browse button and browse
>   to the directory (myGAC/bin/debug)
>   that contains the assembly
>   (myGAC.dll). Locate the assembly,
>   select it, and click OK.

Check this article for details: [How do I create shared assemblies ?](http://www.vkinfotek.com/assemblyhowto.html)

Comment: `Failure adding assembly to the cache : the system can't find the file specified.` when write the assembly file name directly. `unknown option: .......` when write the full path to the dll.

Comment: `You can install the .dll file by using the Gacutil tool or by dragging the .dll file to the appropriate folder.`

I drag the .dll file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your assembly to the GAC thus:

> gacutil /i AssemblyFileName.dll

You can remove it from the GAC thus:

> gacutil /u AssemblyFileName.dll

Comment: `Failure adding assembly to the cache : the system can't find the file specified.` when write the assembly file name directly.

`unknown option: .......` when write the full path to the dll.